# SDL Image (x64) causes 0xc000007b error Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, sdl-2

[image: 0xc0000007b error on compile]

I'm getting this pop up every time I try to run my Visual Studio project with the `SDL_Image` library included. The project runs fine with the `SDL2` by itself.

I've commented out all the code relating to `SDL_Image` but the error persists. Ive read that this error can be caused by a combination of x86 and x64 libraries but I only have the x64 ones included.

I've also noticed it loads and unloads the `dll` file for SDL_Image before the exit codes.

EDIT: Heres the full output from running in debug

```
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Aardhyn\Documents\Repositories\SDL-Game-Engine\SDL Game Engine\x64\Debug\SDL Game Engine.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Aardhyn\Documents\Repositories\SDL-Game-Engine\SDL Game Engine\Dependancies\SDL2\lib\x64\SDL2.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. 
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Aardhyn\Documents\Repositories\SDL-Game-Engine\SDL Game Engine\x64\Debug\SDL2_image.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'SDL Game Engine.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Users\Aardhyn\Documents\Repositories\SDL-Game-Engine\SDL Game Engine\x64\Debug\SDL2_image.dll'
The thread 0x3b88 has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
The thread 0x238c has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
The program '[7776] SDL Game Engine.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
```

I've tried removing and reinstalling the libraries but arrived at the same problem. Any ideas what could be causing this problem or methods to find the issue.

EDIT 2:

Shifting to the `x86` version of `SDL_Image` solves the problem for now.

Comment: The problem is described here: https://github.com/TerryCavanagh/VVVVVV/issues/79.  It might be fixed in a newer version of the library.  It also sounds like a workaround might be to compile your .exe  with a larger stack size.

Comment: Which line causes the error? What does your debugger say?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=0xc000007b+error -- does one of these address a similar issue?

Comment: @paulsm4 that seems like a different error, my issue relates to the SDL_Image library, not SDL2 itself which runs fine.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat There's no specific line that causes an error, I've removed all references to the library from the codebase--something's not right with the library itself. I'm going to try changing all the libraries to the x86 bit versions to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Do you use same SDL lib version as for your app? I refer to 32/64 bits.

Comment: Yes, I made sure all my libraries where on the same architecture.